# Entropy computation in t-SNE of scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy

In the scikit-learn implementation of t-SNE, which is
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f1541b1ca4570177d93fd7979613497e3/sklearn/manifold/_utils.pyx

can someone explain why the entropy is calculated as follows in line 98?

```
entropy = math.log(sum_Pi) + beta * sum_disti_Pi
```

Comment: Your question is interesting, although I do not have an answer. In the original paper, [here](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf), page 4, the entropy for t-SNE is defined in the same way as Shannon's entropy, which is different from the one used in the sklearn implementation.

Comment: I think this kind of question is better to ask: https://datascience.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Another way to look at the issue is: Demonstrate that `math.log(sum_Pi) + beta * sum_disti_Pi` `==` `- sum(Pi * log(Pi) )`.